# Different menu item types in Eclipse 4

Tags: eclipse-rcp, e4

When I right click on a menu and select Add child, I am presented with several options:

- Handled Menu Item
- Menu
- Direct Menu Item
- Dynamic Menu Contribution
- VisibleWhen Core Expression

What is the difference between each of these choices?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Handled Menu Item

  This is a menu item that uses a command id (and therefore one or more  handlers).
- Direct Menu Item

  This is a menu item where you specify the class to handle the item directly without using a command id.
- Menu

  This adds a new sub-menu.
- Dynamic Menu Contribution

  This lets you specify a class that can add multiple menu items dynamically. See [here](http://blog.vogella.com/2013/03/21/dynamic-menu-contributions-in-eclipse-e4/)
- VisibleWhen Core Expression

  This lets you add a 'core expression' to the current menu item to control when it is visible. See the Eclipse help for details of core expressions. Eclipse Oxygen also now supports Imperative Expressions where you can specify a Java class to control the menu visibility.

Comment: Thank you. Are there docs for these that I missed or do you just know these by experience?

Comment: I think the best documentation is the book by Lars Vogel - one of the Eclipse developers. His web site has a shorter tutorial that covers most things [here](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseRCP/article.html)